# Why microsoft edge keep opening this ninja mixer?

Tags: windows-10

This it the exact URL

https://mixer.com/ninja?utm_source=microsoft&utm_medium=pc&utm_campaign=win10spotlightH2g46

I see it went to a microsoft redirector first and then go there.

I search that URL in google and this is what I found

https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2182543-fresh-windows-10-install-edge-keeps-opening-mixer

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-ie-keeps-opening-randomly-with-mixercom/11006e76-ce30-4638-b897-2666e816a77f

I am not the only one with this problem.

It seems that one of microsoft redirector that should redirect somewhere else redirect to that ninja mixer instead.

I wonder why?

Comment: What exactly is your question?  Ninja is a streamer who is exclusively on Mixer.

Comment: The question is exactly what I asked. Microsoft edge keep opening ninja streamer. And I am NOT the only one with that exact problem. There are 2 other people with the exact same problem. I put the link that others have the exact same problem

Comment: From the tracking parameters we can tell this is a Microsoft advertising campaign, probably built into Windows 10.

Comment: Microsoft advertise mixer.com?

Comment: @user4951 - Microsoft advertises their streaming platform, yes, but this is caused by something else that hasn’t been identified

Comment: Most likely it's how it's intended. That mixer ninja guy seems like the throw away traffic if no other advertisers are around.